# Magento review reminder mail does not work since upgrade

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

A while ago we upgraded our magento shop from 1.4 to 1.7. Since then the review reminder is not sent anymore. I'm not 100% what has worked, as I took over this shop and don't know exactly how everything worked before, but I'm pretty sure this reminder has worked in 1.4.

In Magento 1.7, where can I see/set how long it takes to send out a review reminder after a customer has ordered a product? Can I force a review reminder to be sent? I have a test installation and want to try to fix it there first.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions on what I can do or test to get this reminder working again?

---

SOLUTION

It turned out to be a third party module, Aitoc Reviews Booster, that was not upgraded properly. After upgrading the module plus license, it works like it should.

Comment: This feature likely comes from a 3rd-party extension, can you check which one it is ?

Comment: blmage is right about the module being a 3rd-party extension. But this functionality surely needs a cronjob to be configured. Did your host change with the upgrade?

Comment: You're correct. We're using the Aitoc Reviews Booster. I didn't notice before, and it doesn't show in the admin. I'm going to try to reinstall it in a test environment.

Comment: Most likely it's because Aitoc licensing. They have very tricky one, probably you need to drop a line to their support.

Comment: @blmage - if you want you can create an answer and I'll approve that. It took a while but I just installed an upgrade of the aitoc reviews booster and that seems to have worked out. Thanks!

Comment: @SergeiGuk - I did have a small license problem, but that was immediately shown in the admin, so that was fixed within the hour thanks to Aitoc support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature comes from a 3rd-party extension, you should check which one it is, if it is compatible and if it was correctly upgraded.